# Unzipping with Terminal Command

Tags: macos, terminal

I need a command for replacing a Foldername in a path in order to unzip alot of Files within the terminal.

I'm using this to unzip:

```
find ./ * / -name \*.zip -exec unzip {} \;
```

My Folderstructure is for example:

```
Desktop/Exercises/Agata Molicka_1691376_assignsubmission_file_/File1.zip
    
Desktop/Exercises/Alexander Angerer_1691351_assignsubmission_file_/File2.zip
    
Desktop/Exercises/Alexander Rohrauer_1691342_assignsubmission_file_/File3.zip
```

Is there a command to declare a path independently of the folder names ?

```
cd Desktop/Exercises/**HERE**/find ./ -name \*.zip -exec unzip {} \;
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: What is your goal? I presume you're trying to iterate over every zip file and unzip it. You could write a shell script to handle this.

Comment: yes exactly, to unzip all the files in the Folder automated.. unfortunately i'm not that experienced in shell scripts

Comment: Actually, if you're just trying to unzip all zip files in a folder you won't even need a shell script. In your find command, the `./` just means the current directory you're in. So in your case, if you provide the path where the `./` is, it will find all zip files in that directory and execute the unzip command on each.

Comment: In essence, the way you have been running it is moving to a directory and then finding all zip files within that directory to unzip. If I'm understanding right, you want to skip the `cd` part. Which also poses the question, do you want these files unzipped to the same location as the zips are stored, or the current working directory?

Comment: Yes I know that currently it just unzip the files in the current path. But I need to iterate or unzip all the Files in the subfolder of the different folder names. Therefore my first idea was to try if there is something like a wildcard for the path which substitutes just the different folder names. Maybe I have to iterate over all the folders in order to unzip more then 1 file

Comment: You can unzip every subfolder's zip using `find ./path/goes-here -name \*.zip -exec unzip {} \;`, however it will output to your current working directory. I think if you want to unzip into each directory, you'd need a shell script because the passing the directory to the unzip command as an output doesn't seem feasible, since unzip doesn't technically know the current directory the file lives in, just the path to the zip file.

Comment: Okay thanks Dylan, then i might need to get more familiar how to write a shell script for it. Thanks for your time! :)